# How to restrict file extension in operating System dialog box from HTML form

Tags: html

I want to restrict some file types from my html forms that are not necessary in it.
I want the code for my form submission panel.
Here is my code

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <input type="file" name="files"/>    
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"/>    
</form>
```

Comment: I change in the title, First i use Via PHP and now i remove it because i need a code to restrict file types before it is upload that means in openFileDialogBox like C# windowsForms do.

Comment: People have interpreted this as a question about setting restrictions in PHP code (which us actually more relevant than client-side restrictions). If PHP is irrelevant to the question, it should not be tagged with “php”, and PHP cpde should not be included. Besides, you should clarify whether the restriction should be made according to file extension or file type.

Comment: In a comment to an answer, you give additional information that makes it rather unclear what you are really asking.

Comment: what if file name is my.file.jpg when you want the extension use $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: Ok. I got it. Its my mistake because i am a new user. And thanks for your good cooperation.

Comment: or $pos = strrpos($fileName,'.');
$ext = substr($fileName,0,1-$pos);

Comment: @Misunderstood sir, I can restrict file extension via php. 
Sorry to you for my faults, actually i need to restrict file formats from operating systems file browser when we click upload button to upload a file. In the file browser i want to filtered files....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5 you can use "accept" attribute in the input[type=file] tag. For example:

```
<form action="" method="POST" " enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <input type="file" name="files" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif/>    
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" placeholder="Only .jpg/.jpeg files support."/>    
</form>
```

Comment: The SO is asking for a PHP restriction!

Comment: I just wanted to restrict file types that is not necessary for me. If it is done via HTML then it will be ok. But the real question is that, there are several types of file types and if i use accept attribute then i have to write and know a huge mime types. 
  If i got a solution that is suitable and flexible then i will be happy and if not then i have to use accept attribute.

PHP restriction is also needed when i am unable to restrict it from Operating System openDialog Box.

Thanks to all.

Comment: The `accept` value is not consistent with the `placeholder` value (it allows three different image formats). Besides, it is syntactically malformed and sets restrictions by file type, not by filename extension. (The former might be better, but the latter is what the question asks for.)

Comment: @incredible_titan How to get the types to use in accept attribute?
like i want to filter a text file.

Comment: @mpranks, <input type="file" accept="text/plain" />

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

**Limit File Type**

The code below only allows users to upload JPG, JPEG, PNG, and GIF files. All other file types gives an error message before setting $uploadOk to 0:

```
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

**Complete Upload Example**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  
But if i get a code by which i can restrict file types to upload then its better.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <div id="upload_box" style="width : 200px; height : 200px; position : fixed; top : 300px; left : 400px; display : none;">

           Select File :-  Only jpg and jpeg supported !
           <input type="file" id="fl" name="files" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg" />

     </div>

     <button id="show_dialog"> Select File </button>
     <input type="submit">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).on('click', '#show_dialog', function(){
          $('#upload_box').css({'display' : 'block'});  // show box when click on 
     });

     $(document).on('change', '#fl', function(){
         $('#upload_box').css({'display' : 'none'});  // hide box when file selected 
     });
```

:) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To restrict to jpg and jpeg by MIME Type

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']) 
   AND $_FILES['files']['error'] ==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  if (strtolower($_FILES['files']['type']) != 'image/jpeg'){
   //not jpg code 
}
```

**Additional Check** if uploaded file is not a jpg but has jpg extension and or MIME Type.
Requires GD Image Processing Extension 
**This is the most rigorous test.** The file is completely analyzed.  $image can also be converted to other image types, resized, text annotations added, and a lot more.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

```
$image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);
if ($image == false){
   //not jpg code 

}
```

Or if not going to resize etc..
You can restrict by MIME Type, dimensions, attributes
Requires GD Image Processing Extension

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);
```